# node.js CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory ERROR

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I faced that problem during forEach cycle over my object parsed by xml2js from xml inside cycle over 'products' objects from mongoDB:
So my code is here:

```
 Product.find(function(err, products){
            if(err)return updateDBCallback(err);

            if(products.length > 0) {

                products.forEach(function (dbProduct) {
                    var equals = false;

                    xmlFile.product_list.product.forEach(function (product) {

                        var productEntity = new Product({
                            product_id: parseInt(product.id),
                            parent_id: parseInt(product.parent_id),
                            sku: product.sku,
                            title: product.title,
                            pricenormal: parseFloat(product.price_normal),
                            pricewholesale: parseFloat(product.price_wholesale),
                            pricewholesalelarge: parseFloat(product.price_wholesale_large),
                            pricesale: parseFloat(product.price_sale),
                            weight: parseFloat(product.weight),
                            volume: parseFloat(product.volume),
                            unittype: product.unit_type,
                            status: product.status,
                            datecreating: product.datecreating,
                            sp: product.sp,
                            guaranteeext: product.guarantee_ext,
                            used: product.used,
                            statusfull: product.status_full,
                            description: null,
                            url: null
                        });
                        items.push(productEntity);

                        if (dbProduct.product_id === productEntity.product_id){
                            log.info(" produt eqauls " + dbProduct.product_id + " =" + productEntity.product_id );
                            equals = true;
                        }
                    });
                     if (!equals) {
                        log.warn("Remove PRODUCT " + dbProduct);
                        Product.remove({ _id: dbProduct._id }, function (err) {
                            if (err) return updateDBCallback(err);
                        });
                    }

                });
```

So after some cycles I got `CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory ERROR` error. I saw similar questions and someone says what `-max_old_space_size` parameter can solve the issue. But why did that happens?

**UPDATE1:**
I think I found out the problem in   `items.push(productEntity);` so I got 5000 items at my db, and 5000 products at 'xmlfile' , so my items array grows to very large size

Comment: even I'm getting similar error. Did you find the resolution?

Comment: as for me that was just invalid embedded for.each loop , so its iterates over 5000*5000 cycles. And my items array size increase to a huge size. Could you pls provide your code?

Comment: This may be a solution for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/25598816/3765109